# Convertir una fecha a decimal

Tags: oracle

Tengo este casteo en mi SP de Oracle pero al momento de agruparlo me dice que no se puede por el mismo tema mas sin embargo si puedo correrlo afuera con un simple select, alguien sabe si hay alguna manera alterna de hacer esto?

```
    SELECT case when START_TIME > 24*60*60*30 then cast(cast(EXTRACT(YEAR from E.ON_DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) || substr('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(month from E.ON_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)),-2,2) || substr('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(day from E.ON_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)),-2,2) as NUMBER(9))  + 1 
else 
cast(cast(EXTRACT(YEAR from E.ON_DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) || substr('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(month from E.ON_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)),-2,2) || substr('00' || CAST(EXTRACT(day from E.ON_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)),-2,2) as NUMBER(9)) END TIEMPO_NUEVO
FROM EVENT E
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien, la consulta que has compartido en la pregunta funciona correctamente. Para darte la ayuda adecuada, por favor comparte con nosotros el código que **no** funciona correctamente, así como el error **exacto** (palabra por palabra) que te da.

Comment: Gracias, deje la especificacion de mi SP en una repuesta

Comment: @CrisValdez Hola, no lo coloques como respuesta, por favor edita la pregunta y agregalo ahí ...

Comment: Lo que dice @Goerman, y luego borras la respuesta. También, por favor no te olvides de incluir el error exacto (palabra por palabra).

Comment: @Cris: Veo que borrastes la respuesta (o alguien lo hice por ti). Pero por favor no te olvides agregar el SP a tu pregunta. Porque ahora la respuesta que te di no tiene sentido, porque nadie puede ver el SP.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno de una vez puede notar uno de los problemas. Se te olvidó el `case when` en frente de `START_TIME > 24*60*60*30 then ...`, tanto en el `SELECT` como en el `GROUP BY`. Tal vez tengas otros problemas, pero vas a tener que compartir el error exacto para poder ayudarte mejor.

En cuanto a lo que es el título de tu pregunta:

> Convertir una fecha a decimal

... te propongo una forma más sencilla de hacerlo:

```
(EXTRACT(YEAR from E.ON_DATE) * 10000)
+ (EXTRACT(month from E.ON_DATE) * 100)
+ EXTRACT(day from E.ON_DATE)
```